# Redirect URLs with query strings in .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, concrete5

I'm trying to migrate an old site to a new one built with concrete5. The old site uses query strings, which I cannot redirect from within concrete5.

1. There are multiple categories, how can I redirect just the query part?

   - Old URL: `example.com/portfolio/category?cat=hifi`
   - New URL: `example.com/projecten/hifi`
2. Further I have URLs with a different query also needing redirects:

   - Old URL: `example.com/portfolio/post.php?s=pagename-xxx-xxx`
   - New URL: `example.com/projecten/pagename-xxx-xxx`

Help very much appreciated!

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use mod_rewrite and a *condition* (`RewriteCond`) that matches against the `QUERY_STRING` server variable.

Try the following in your root `.htaccess` file *above* any existing mod_rewrite directives.

```
RewriteEngine On

# PART 1 : Redirect old category URLs
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cat=(\w+)
RewriteRule ^portfolio/category$ /projecten/%1? [R=302,L]

# PART 2 : Redirect other old URLs
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^s=(pagename-\w{3}-\w{3})
RewriteRule ^portfolio/post\.php$ /projecten/%1? [R=302,L]
```

This assumes that the `xxx` in `pagename-xxx-xxx` are 3 literal word characters (ie. `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9` or `_`).

**UPDATE#1:** The trailing `?` on the `RewriteRule` substitution is necessary in order to remove the query string from the target. Or, use the `QSD` flag on Apache 2.4+.

Change the `302` (temporary) redirect to `301` (permanent) when you are sure it's working OK. 301 redirects are cached by the browser, which can make testing problematic.

**UPDATE#2:** With respect to the updated URL in "PART 2", try the following instead:

```
# PART 2 : Redirect other old URLs
# To essentially remove the date prefix, eg. "YYYY-MM-DD-"
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^s=/d{4}-/d{2}-/d{2}-(.+)
RewriteRule ^portfolio/post\.php$ /projecten/%1? [R=302,L]
```

> `^s=[0-9{4}]+-(.+?)/?[0-9{2}]+-(.+?)/?[0-9{2}]+-(.+?)/?(.*)$`

This is a bit of a *mash*, but also looks overly complex for what you are trying to achieve? For instance, why do you need to match an *optional* slash (ie. `/?`)? Your example URL does not contain any slashes?

A regex pattern such as `[0-9{4}]+` isn't doing what you think it's doing. This would match any of the characters `0123456789{}` 1 or more times. What you seem to be trying to do is to match exactly 4 digits. eg. `[0-9]{4}` (which is the same as `/d{4}`, using a shorthand character class).

Comment: The first part is working but the second part is not. I did not explain the right url. i will post underneath.

Comment: I've updated my answer with respect to your revised URL structure. I've also added the `?` on the substitution that I missed earlier (I see you've used the QSD flag instead - that is an alternative on Apache 2.4+).

Comment: Yeah, i was trying to follow some examples i found to remove numbers and dashes. But obviously i did not know what i was doing... Your nwe code works perfectly, thanks a million!!!